# Adjunction via universal morphisms implies adjunction via unit-counit

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

I know there is a fair amount of similar questions to this one, but none of them deal directly with what I'm struggling with right now. For instance, in [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690971/equivalence-of-the-definition-of-adjoint-functors-via-universal-morphisms-and-un) the right adjoint functor is constructed, while in my situation I already have the pair of functors. In [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048512/deriving-unit-counit-identities) the objective is to derive the unit-counit equations, (which is the same I'm trying to prove, essentially), but this question does not have any answers. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603882/do-counit-unit-adjunctions-have-the-expected-universal-properties) deals with the converse, but that direction I was able to prove.

**Goal**

> Given functors $L \colon C \to D, R \colon D \to C$, a family of morphisms $\eta_X \colon X \to RL(X), \epsilon_Y \colon LR(Y) \to Y$ such that $\forall f \colon L(X) \to Y. \exists ! g \colon X \to R(Y). f= \epsilon_Y \circ L(g) \land g=R(f) \circ \eta_X$ and vice-versa (for every $g$ there is an unique $f$), then $\eta: id_C \to RL, \epsilon: LR \to id_D$ are natural transformations and the natural-transformation-equalities hold.

First I need to prove that $\eta$ is a natural transformation. That is, given a morphism $f \colon X_1 \to X_2$ in $C$, we have $\eta_{X_2} \circ f = RL(f) \circ \eta_{X_1}$.

**What I did**

Define $g = \eta_{X_2} \circ f$. By hypothesis, there exists an unique $f' \colon L(X_1) \to L(X_2)$ such that $\epsilon_{L(X_2)} \circ L(g) = f'$ and $g= R(f') \circ \eta_{X_1}$. Hence $\eta_{X_2} \circ f = R(f') \circ \eta_{X_1}$. It is sufficient to prove $R(f')=RL(f)$. After some calculations, we have $R(f') = R(\epsilon_{L(X_2)} \circ L(\eta_{X_2})) \circ RL(f)$. How to prove that $R(\epsilon_{L(X_2)} \circ L(\eta_{X_2})) = id_{RL(X_2)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the morphism $id_{L(X_2)} \colon L(X_2) \to L(X_2)$. By hypothesis, there exists an unique $g \colon X_2 \to RL(X_2)$ such that $\epsilon_{L(X_2)} \circ L(g) = id_{L(X_2)}$ and $g=id_{RL(X_2)} \circ \eta_{X_2}$. But the only $g$ such that the second equality holds is $g=\eta_{X_2}$, hence $\epsilon_{L(X_2)} \circ L(\eta_{X_2}) = id_{L(X_2)}$.